# How to use the QVector container with a custom class?

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

Here's a custom class I implemented for a personal project:

```
#include <QtCore/QCommandLineOption>
#include <QtCore/QSharedPointer>

#include <genepy/cli/CommandLineArgument.h>
#include <genepy/cli/CommandLineOption.h>

class QCommandLineParser;

namespace genepy {

class CommandLineParserBuilder;
class ConsoleApplication;

class GENEPY_EXPORT CommandLineParser {
public:
    static CommandLineParserBuilder create(const ConsoleApplication& application);

    void doParsing();

    template <typename T>
    T getArgumentValue(const QString& name) const;

    bool isOptionPresent(const QString& name) const;

    template <typename T>
    T getOptionValue(const QString& name) const;

private:
    friend class CommandLineParserBuilder;

    explicit CommandLineParser(const ConsoleApplication& application);

    const QSharedPointer<QCommandLineParser> parser_;

    const QCommandLineOption helpOption_;
    const QCommandLineOption versionOption_;

    QVector<CommandLineArgument> arguments_;

    QVector<CommandLineOption> options_;
};

} // namespace genepy
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/SPlesskin/genepy/tree/develop).

When I compile this code with Qt 5.15 on Windows (MinGW, MSVC), there's no problem. However, on Debian 9 with Qt 5.7, I get this error :

```
In file included from /home/erwan/git/genepy/include/genepy/cli/CommandLineParserBuilder.h:29:0,
                 from /home/erwan/git/genepy/src/cli/CommandLineParser.cpp:29:
/home/erwan/git/genepy/include/genepy/cli/CommandLineParser.h:94:34: error: field ‘arguments_’ has incomplete type ‘QVector<genepy::CommandLineArgument>’
     QVector<CommandLineArgument> arguments_;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1139:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qalgorithms.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstringlist.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qcommandlineparser.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QCommandLineParser:1,
                 from /home/erwan/git/genepy/src/cli/CommandLineParser.cpp:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:189:1: note: declaration of ‘class QVector<genepy::CommandLineArgument>’
 Q_DECLARE_MOVABLE_CONTAINER(QVector);
 ^
In file included from /home/erwan/git/genepy/include/genepy/cli/CommandLineParserBuilder.h:29:0,
                 from /home/erwan/git/genepy/src/cli/CommandLineParser.cpp:29:
/home/erwan/git/genepy/include/genepy/cli/CommandLineParser.h:97:32: error: field ‘options_’ has incomplete type ‘QVector<genepy::CommandLineOption>’
     QVector<CommandLineOption> options_;
                                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1139:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qalgorithms.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstringlist.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qcommandlineparser.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QCommandLineParser:1,
                 from /home/erwan/git/genepy/src/cli/CommandLineParser.cpp:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:189:1: note: declaration of ‘class QVector<genepy::CommandLineOption>’
 Q_DECLARE_MOVABLE_CONTAINER(QVector);
 ^
```

I've no clue on what's going wrong with this code... Can someone help me? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you try adding `#include <QVector>`?

Comment: Did you declare your type using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO?

More information on it : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I changed `QVector<CommandLineArgument>` to `QVector<QSharedPointer<CommandLineArgument>>` since `CommandLineArgument` wasn't an *assignable data type* (it was missing a default constructor among others). Now, it works.